# Avançar aba ao clicar no botão

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-3

Possuo um formulário para cadastro dividido em abas, onde as abas estão desabilitadas até o usuário clicar no botão para habilitar e ir para próxima. O problema é que da forma que está o usuário tem que habilitar o botão e em seguida clicar na próxima aba.
Preciso que quando o usuário clicar no botão **PRÓXIMO** ele seja direcionado para a próxima aba automaticamente, e adicionar um botão para retornar para a aba anterior.

Meu código está assim atualmente: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/randrade/mqjs2yqb/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id='content' class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
          Nome: <input/><br/>
          <button>Próximo</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
          CPF: <input/><br/>
          <button>Próximo</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">

          <button>Salvar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*disable non active tabs*/
    $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");

    $('button').click(function(){
        /*enable next tab*/
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab")
    });
});
```

Eu preciso de algo parecido como isso: [Exemplo](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-disabletabclick.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A forma mais simples que vejo é acionar o evento `click` na aba. Basta adicionar um `trigger("click")` na linha que habilita a mesma:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    /*enable next tab*/
    $('.nav li.active').next('li').removeClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab").trigger("click");
});
```

---

Para dicionar um botão para voltar é bem simples. Você pode adicionar o botão diretamente no html. Recomendo que você comece a utilizar classes ou até ids para identificar seus botões.

Segue exemplo completo:

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<div id='content' class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">
        Nome: <input/><br/>
        <button class="next">Próximo</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">
        CPF: <input/><br/>
        <button class="prev">Anterior</button>
        <button class="next">Próximo</button>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
        <button class="prev">Anterior</button>
        <button class="save">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*disable non active tabs*/
    $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");

    $('button.next').click(function(){
        /*enable next tab*/
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').removeClass('disabled');
        $('.nav li.active').next('li').find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab").trigger("click");
    });

    $('button.prev').click(function() {
        $('.nav li.active').prev('li').find('a').trigger("click");
    });
});
```

Comment: Isso resolveu a parte de avançar corretamente. Você teria uma sugestão de como adicionar o botão para retornar para a aba anterior?

Answer (score 3):

Com certeza a resposta do Oeslei é melhor, mas estou deixando aqui uma forma manual de se fazer isso:

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqjs2yqb/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /*disable non active tabs*/
    $('.nav li').not('.active').addClass('disabled');
    $('.nav li').not('.active').find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    
    $('button.next').click(function(){
        $lia = $('.nav li.active');
        $li = $('.nav li.active').next('li');
        
        /*enable next tab*/
        $li.removeClass('disabled');
        $li.find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab");
        /*toggle tab*/
        $li.find('a').click();
        
        /*disable previous tab*/
        $lia.addClass('disabled');
        $lia.find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    });
    $('button.previous').click(function(){
        $lia = $('.nav li.active');
        $li = $('.nav li.active').prev('li');
        
        /*enable next tab*/
        $li.removeClass('disabled');
        $li.find('a').attr("data-toggle","tab");
        /*toggle tab*/
        $li.find('a').click();
        
        /*disable previous tab*/
        $lia.addClass('disabled');
        $lia.find('a').removeAttr("data-toggle");
    });
});
```

Comment: Seu código me ajudou com a lógica, muito obrigado.